# Creating a dynamic enum and attempting to reference it fail with BindingFailure

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, reflection.emit

I need to create a dynamic enum and then be able to get the type using Type.GetType(). Is this possible?

The below code will create a dynamic enum, and attempt to use it's qualifying name. This is fine if I first store the assembly (using AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave). However, this is not possible if I'm solely using AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run; a BindingFailure error occur; unable to find the assembly. My impression was that the Run option would allow creation and usage without having to actually store the assembly (or having access to the different Builders).

(Note: The below code usage of Type.GetType() is not mine. I cannot change that code.)

How can I, without storing the assembly, create a dynamic enum and reference it?

```
        private Type CreateType()
        {          
        // Define the assembly.
        System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new System.Reflection.AssemblyName("temporaryAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

        // Actually create it.
        System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("temporaryAssembly");

        // Create the enum.
        System.Reflection.Emit.EnumBuilder enumBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineEnum("Temp", System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));

        /* Populate the enum. */

                    return enumBuilder.CreateType();
        }

        private void DoStuff()
        {
                    Type t = CreateType();
                    Type createAnotherOfSameType = Type.GetType(t.AssemblyQualifiedName);
        }/
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) now:

> GetType only works on assemblies loaded from disk. If you call GetType
>   to look up a type defined in a dynamic assembly defined using the
>   System.Reflection.Emit services, you might get inconsistent behavior.
>   The behavior depends on whether the dynamic assembly is persistent,
>   that is, created using the RunAndSave or Save access modes of the
>   System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess enumeration. [...] If the
>   assembly has not been saved to disk when GetType is called, the method
>   returns null. GetType does not understand transient dynamic
>   assemblies; therefore, calling GetType to retrieve a type in a
>   transient dynamic assembly returns null.

The docs then go on by saying that you can subscribe AppDomain.AssemblyResolve to resolve a dynamic assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to do there. Two problems: 1) the second line is just trying to get a reference to the Type again, which will be the same reference as the first line; it's not an instance you're getting. 2) IIRC, AssemblyQualifiedName is null for an in-memory type/assembly.

-Oisin

Comment: The second line will be done in another assembly. I will pass 't' to the assembly which will later handle it, using that particular code. Above was just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: By the way, AssemblyQualifiedName actually return the (seemingly) correct information.